# Join more than two tables using Annotations in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've three entities: `A`, `B` and `C`, and the relation between them is as following:

```
class A{
    @ManyToMany
    List<B> bs;
    //other attributes and getter setters
}

class B{

    @ManyToMany
    List<C> cs;
    //other attributes and getter setters
}

class C{
    //other attributes and getter setters
}
```

But from my current entity classes, I can make relation between any 2 tables using `@JoinTable`. But what I want is to save relation between all 3 entities in a separate table, having primary keys of these entities as columns. (Foreign keys)

If we assume entities `B` and `C` are already saved (inserted) into database and I insert new entity of `A` as following:

```
A:{
  "A_id": 1
  B:[
    "B_id": 1
    {
      C:[
          {"C_id": 1}, {"C_id": 2}
        ]
    }, 
    {
      "B_id": 2
      C:[
          {"C_id": 2}
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Then `A` should be saved in it's table and the relations should be listed in a separate table as following:

```
A_id    B_id    C_id
=====================
 1       1       1
 1       1       2
 1       2       2
```

One of the related question I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472440/how-to-join-three-tables-using-a-single-table-in-hibernate). But I think my scenario is different as I've many to many relations between all the entities `A`, `B` and `C`.

I'm not asking for full code. Any approach or exact reference will be fine as long as it solves the purpose. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've tried implementing the separate relation table as mentioned in the answer. But the problem with this approach is that, when I remove a row from the relation table, It also removes the entry from the join table of `B` and `C`. (Affects the previous relation of entities `B` and `C`)

Also while updating updating the row, it changes (performs insert) into the join table of entity `B` and `C`. Which is not expected behavior. I want this table for just storing the relation between the entities and not for changing previous relations between those entities.

Following is my new relation table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relation_table")
public class RelationEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk_relation_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer relatoinId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
    private C c;

    //getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Any reason WHY you want that? Looks like broken concept to me

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the `relation` in separate table then you can simply do something like this to save `primary keys`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relation_bridge")
public class RelationBridge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c")
    private C c;

    //getters & setters
}
```

**EDIT**

> When I remove a row from the relation table, It also removes the entry >from the join table of `B` and `C`. (Affects the previous relation of >entities `B` and `C`)

The above solution should not `delete` the entries in a `parent` table unless explicitly defined. However you may be using other mappings in your other classes so this behavior can be controlled by applying [Cascading](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) in your mappings.

[A Beginner's Guide to JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types](https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and)

[Good read for beginners](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate)

Comment: Arguably, the surrogate key could even be dropped in favor of making each association a part of the primary key. This way, there would be a natural unique constraint on the join columns.

Comment: Yes @crizzis you are right, but in my problem I was also using this table `foreign key` in another table with some other values and then that `surrogate key` really help to `query` things easily. Thats why I left it in the answer considering it can also help the readers

Comment: @Kaushal28 I mentioned `@ManyToOne` not ManyToMany

Comment: It depends on your problem, you can keep it `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne`. Considering `A` is Manager and `B` is Supervisor then `ManyToOne` would be a better choice as a manager can lead multiple supervisors.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when I remove the entry from this relation table, it also removes the relation between my table `B` and `C`.

Comment: @Kaushal28 answer update. Also make sure you are using proper cascading in other relations/parent

Comment: Which cascade type should I use?

Comment: @Kaushal28 you can user `merge` if you dont want to create a new entry and want to merge it with the older one. Make sure you pass the `id` when setting object

Answer (score 0):

And what about using your new class RelationEntity with A nullable. When you intent to remove the "new" relationship you update it putting null in A property. It's just a suggestion, forgive if you cannot make it this way.